# Only White Screen is showing and no Image display in WebView

Tags: android, url, webview, android-webview

User should be able to view the image when they have clicked on the image thumbnail, however, all that is displayed is a white screen with a refresh button. The behaviour is consistent for all images selected, the WebView method has been utilised in the following implementation. I have tried to adjust the width and height layout as I suspected that the dimension of the image was out of range to be displayed in the android device. However, that rectification implementation didn't work as well. What has gone wrong? Any suggestions?

I have attached the following code copy for your perusal:

***Code:***

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.invalidate();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(1);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                photoPb.setProgress(newProgress);
                if (newProgress != 100) {
                    photoPb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    if (apb == null)
                        apb = new BgPbAsyncTask().execute();
                    else if (apb.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING
                            && apb.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.PENDING)
                        apb = new BgPbAsyncTask().execute();
                }
            }
        });
        if (panoSize > 0) {
            g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery01);
            g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
            int pad = 15;
            g.setSpacing(1);
            g.setUnselectedAlpha(255);
            g.setPadding(pad, 10, pad, pad);
            g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    img_id = position+1;
                    setImageShade(position);
                    captionText.setText(caption[position]);

                    Log.i("PropertyPanoramaActvity:if(panoSize>0)","******webView.loadUrl******"+getString(R.string.app_360_domain)+getString(R.string.app_360_property)+(getIntent().getIntExtra("propertyId", 0))+getString(R.string.app_360_directory)+(img_id)+getString(R.string.app_360_index));

                    webView.loadUrl(String.format(getString(R.string.app_360_domain)
                            +getString(R.string.app_360_property)+(getIntent().getIntExtra("propertyId", 0))
                            +getString(R.string.app_360_directory)+img_id
                            +getString(R.string.app_360_index)));

                    /*if (flashInstalled) {
                        webView.loadUrl(img[position].getPanoUrl());   
                    } else {
                        webView.loadUrl(String.format("https://developer.dapoltd.com/spacetobe_uat/data/images/property/property107/360/4/index.htm", id, img_id));

                        //webView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.wap_domain) + getString(R.string.wap_flashnotsupported));
                    }*/

                }
            });
        }
```

***Android Manifest***

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

***XML layout***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/transparent">
<include layout="@layout/header" />
<include layout="@layout/property_nav" />
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent">
    <include layout="@layout/property_share" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"></WebView>
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/photoPb" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="5dp"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<include layout="@layout/mainmenu" />
```

Comment: can you Log the URL that is being passed to the WebView. i.e. this: Log.d("URL", String.format(getString(R.string.app_360_domain)
                            +getString(R.string.app_360_property)+(getIntent().getIntExtra("propertyId", 0))
                            +getString(R.string.app_360_directory)+img_id
                            +getString(R.string.app_360_index)));

Comment: @samgak yes, it is possible, the following log is ` 01-22 13:16:47.889: I/PropertyPanoramaActvity:if(panoSize>0)(16564): ******webView.loadUrl******https://developer.dapoltd.com/spacetobe_uat/data/images/property/property135/360/3/ `

Comment: I tested (part of) your code and it works for me. Panorama appears and I can look around.

Comment: @samgak As in all images are displaying?? However, the images that I require are not displayed but just a white screen. Do you mind if you can share what considerations you might have taken?

Comment: I used an XML layout with a single WebView, and used your code for initializing the webview (up to but not including the if(panosize > 0) statement). Then I copied the code from inside your setOnItemClickListener function and loaded the Url. It opened up the panorama.

Comment: @samgak do you mind if you could do the code edit so that I can view it properly? It is a lil bit confusing over here

Comment: I don't have enough rep for that sorry, it wouldn't show up until someone else approved it

Comment: @samgak   How about just provide the answer below pls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69372/discussion-between-samgak-and-androidnoob).